# Node.js: Custom header returns undefined when use 'req.header'

Tags: node.js, http-headers, request-headers, response-headers, custom-headers

I'm fairly new to Express and NodeJS. I'm having trouble accessing my custom created header named `auth-token` when trying to verify the existing of said user first before allowing them to do any **CRUD** functionality in the system. It just returned `'undefined'` instead of the **token** I placed in it.

So below is where I created my **custom header** named `auth-token` in my **home GET router**.

```
// Home GET Router
router.get('/', verifyUser, async (req, res) => {

    // get user data by id
    const dbData = await All.findById({ _id: req.user._id })

    // store token passed as query 'tkn' in 'token' var
    const token = req.query.tkn

    // create custom header & render 'index.ejs' or homepage
    res
       .header('auth-token', token)
       .render('index', { data: dbData.data })
}
```

I successfully able to create the custom header `auth-token` with no problem as shown below in my index or home page:

[image]

Right now, I'm trying to **save new data** inserted by user in the home page by using **Home POST Router** as shown below. But it will check first whether the user has the token or not using `verifyUser1st` function:

```
// Home POST Router
router.post('/', verifyUser1st, async (req, res) => {

    // save new data code here...
}
```

And this is my `verifyUser1st` function:

```
function verifyUser1st(req, res, next) {

    // get token from header
    const token = req.header('auth-token') // this will return undefined

    // if have, then allow/continue next(). If don't have, then return error message
    if(!token) return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Accessed Denied!' }) // I got this error since token = undefined

    try {

        // verify the exist token
        const varified = jwt.verify(token, process.env.TOKEN_4LOGINUSER)
        req.user = varified
        next()
    } catch(err) {

        res.status(400).json({ message: 'Invalid token!' })
    }
}
```

But unfortunately it returns **Accessed Denied** since the token is **undefined**.

Should the `auth-token` be in **Request Headers** section **(in blue circle image above)** instead of **Response Header** section **(in red circle image above)** in order for it to work?

If **yes**, then how can I do that? If **not**, then can you help enlighten me of what things or topics should I learn first in order for me to make this work since I'm kinda new to this HTTP, Express and NodeJS environment?

Answer (score 0):

to answer your question briefly - if you want to pass the auth token in the header then it should be passed in the request header.

However, if you want some middleware to check a token value that you can use later on in the processing chain, then just set it as a custom property on the req object and access it from there. There is no reason to try to jam something into the headers and then parse it out again later.

```
const auth = (req, res, next) => {
let { token } = req.body;
try {
    console.log(token)
    if (!token)
        return res.status(401).json({ msg: 'no authentication token, authorisation denied' })

    const verified = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_KEY);
    if (!verified)
        return res.status(401).json({ msg: 'no authentication token, authorisation denied' })

    req.user = verified.id;
    next();
}
catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });
}
}
```

So instead of sending the token in a Header we can either grab it from somewhere in the state, or in your case from the local storage.

In the front end we would do something like   `const token = localStorage.getItem("auth-token");`

And then we would pass this token to the API request.